# Using $row = mssql_fetch_object breaks the second $row?

Tags: php, sql-server

**Situation:**

I am coding PHP (5.2.1) and want to process a mssql result.

```
$sql = "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE foo = '123'";
$ret = mssql_query ( $sql );
```

the select and the $ret result is fine, i tested it multiple times.

```
var_dump($ret); //output is: resource(597) of type (mssql result)
```

**Question:**

my code contains `$row = mssql_fetch_object ( $ret );` twice because i copy & pasted some code. Like this:

```
$row = mssql_fetch_object ( $ret );
var_dump($row);
...
...
$row = mssql_fetch_object ( $ret );
var_dump($row);
```

the first `var_dump($row);` shows a valid object:

```
(object(stdClass)#139 (2) {
  ["XXX"]=>
  string(10) "ASDFASD"....)
```

but the second `var_dump($row);`  is `boolean(false)`.

How is that possible? Does mssql_fetch_object() affect $ret? I checked both $ret results and they were the same..

What am I missing?

thanks for your help.

Comment: fetch functions moves the internal pointer each time called. If you have only one row, first time calling fetch_object will return the first row, second time calling it will return false as there is no more stream to be fetched

Comment: getting false from a fetch operation means there's no more data to fetch. e.g. your query only returned one row, and you've already fetched it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you have already fetched the object when you have done the first

```
$row = mssql_fetch_object ( $ret );
```

If you want to reuse the same row just use $row again.

```
$row = mssql_fetch_object ( $ret );
var_dump($row);
...
...
var_dump($row);
```

The function mssql_fetch_object is used in a while() statement so when it returns false it means that there aren't more rows in the result.

**A quick example.**

You do a SELECT that returns 3 rows. And you run the following code:

```
$row1 = mssql_fetch_object ( $ret );
$row2 = mssql_fetch_object ( $ret );
$row3 = mssql_fetch_object ( $ret );
$row4 = mssql_fetch_object ( $ret );

var_dump($row1);
var_dump($row2);
var_dump($row3);
var_dump($row4);
```

You will receive something like the following

```
array( <row 1 items> )
array( <row 2 items> )
array( <row 3 items> )
false
```

Because you are trying to get the 4th row, however your result only has 3 rows.

So instead of doing the previous piece of code you should do something like this:

```
while($row1 = mssql_fetch_object ( $ret ))
{
     var_dump($row)
}
```

So when there are no more rows the while exits and you continue your code and you will receive something like the following

```
array( <row 1 items> )
array( <row 2 items> )
array( <row 3 items> )
```